# Difference between 'void' and ' <T> void' in java method

Tags: java, generics, return, return-type, consumer

```
public static <T> void myMethod(int a, Consumer<T> consumer){// Some code}
```

```
public static void myMethod(int a, Consumer<T> consumer){// Some code}
```

Difference between 'void' and '<T> void'

Comment: The second one doesn't compile, unless `T` is an existing type (class, interface, enum, or type parameter on the enclosing class/interface). Please [edit] your question to include the class definition

Comment: <T> in the first method means this method accepts a generic type T in it's arguments. Second method accepts a non-generic type T which must exist

Comment: Since he didn't attach the rest, i assumed he didn't declare it anywhere else. But yes, @user16320675, that's also a possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `<T> void`.  These are two entirely separate declarations (`<T>` and `void`) that happen to be next to each other:

```
public static <T> void myMethod(int a, Consumer<T> consumer){/* Some code */}
//             │    │
//             │    └─ Declaration of method's return type
//             │
//             └────── Declaration of a generic type which is used only
//                     by this method
```

And how is this different?

```
public static void myMethod(int a, Consumer<T> consumer){/* Some code */}
```

In the above line, `<T>` is not declared anywhere, so the declaration will not compile.  (If the method were not static, it could use the `<T>` declared on the enclosing class, assuming the enclosing class declares a `<T>` type.)